# How do i use TextRange in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, namespaces, richtextbox, textrange

I am using the following code i found online,

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/750a654e-b002-4742-8f46-609e93f6ec81

where i can save RichTextBox content to SQL DB but i am unable to use TextRange in my Sliverlight file how do i include? which namespace? if any will that namespace work in Silverlight?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: `TextRange` doesn't exist in Silverlight, what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: thanks for responding I would like to convert Xaml to rtf and i found many that work in WPF but so far none in Silverlight so how do i convert xaml to rtf?

Comment: To get the entire contents of the RichTextBox you can use the `Xaml` property. (I've edited my answer accordingly).  However I'm not aware of any non-commercial component that will parse Xaml and convert it to RTF.  Must it be RTF, will HTML suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for the `TextRange` in Silverlight. The closest you'll get is the `TextSelection` object which merely represents the range of text that the user has selected.  You can't manipulate the selection yourself, except by calling `SelectAll` on the `RichTextBox`.

**Edit**

If you just want to access the entire contents a RichTextBox as Xaml then you can use its `Xaml` property.